# How can i listen or check if the button is being pressed for 2nd time in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm trying to create a follow button like instagram in flutter but i got a problem.

If user clicks the button for first time, the button state will change. Until this the code is working fine, but now i'm stuck at when user presses the same button which is now from `Follow` to `Following`. If he/she presses button, the button would go back to its original state from `Following` to `Follow`.

How can i do this?

I'm trying to add listener, but i cant figure it out how to implement this. Now I'm trying to create a function for button in which if it is being pressed for 2nd time from same user it will go back to its original state.

```
 bool isButtonPressed = false;  
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).update({
  'following' : FieldValue.increment(1),
});
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(docId).collection('Followers').add({
  'follower' : username,
  'userid' : docid,
  'avatar' : profile,
});
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(docId).update({
  'followers' : FieldValue.increment(1),
});
print(docid);
```

and my button widget code:

```
 ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        getCurrentUser();
                        setState(() {
                          isButtonPressed = true;
                        });
                        },
                      style: isButtonPressed ? ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        onPrimary: Colors.white24,
                        primary: Colors.white24,
                      ) :
                      ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.blue,
                        onPrimary: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50 ,  right:50 ),
                        child: isButtonPressed ? Text(
                            "Following",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                        ) :
                            Text(
                              "Follow",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            )
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Could you please share some code with us? It'll be easier to help

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella updated question embedded the code also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ToggleButton, no need to reinvent the wheel.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html

```
ToggleButtons(
  children: <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
    Icon(Icons.call),
    Icon(Icons.cake),
  ],
  onPressed: (int index) {
    setState(() {
      isSelected[index] = !isSelected[index];
    });
  },
  isSelected: isSelected,
),
```

If you want to edit your original code you can try this:

```
ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        getCurrentUser();
                        setState(() {
                          isButtonPressed = !isButtonPressed;
                        });
                        },
                      style: isButtonPressed ? ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        onPrimary: Colors.white24,
                        primary: Colors.white24,
                      ) :
                      ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.blue,
                        onPrimary: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50 ,  right:50 ),
                        child: isButtonPressed ? Text(
                            "Following",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                        ) :
                            Text(
                              "Follow",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            )
                      ),
                    ),
```

Changing this line in the code:

```
setState(() {
                              isButtonPressed = !isButtonPressed;
                            });
```

will make the button toggle true/false for each press

Comment: i couldn`t understand it quite well it will create 2 buttons but what do i need is apply different function on same button with changing text and color when certain conditions are met!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you wanted . Look at my edit maybe this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **DoubleTap** gesture I suggest

Comment: dobule tap changes my whole follow button logic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).